# How to localise an Apple help book

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization

I built a help book for my cocoa application and registered it in my Info.plist file.

The book opens, but I am unable to open the localised version.

These are the contents of my directory:

```
Contents/
    Info.plist
    PkfInfo
    Resources/
        en.lproj/
            index.html
            InfoPlist.strings
            locale-info.json
        index.html
        shrd/
    version.plist
```

When I open the help book the index from the Resources folder is loaded, not the one in the en.lproj. When I remove the "global" index, I get an "The selected topic is currently unavailable." error.

How do I localise the help book correctly?

UPDATE:
I found out one way is to copy the .help bundle into the language folders of my application, but then I have 8 different .help bundles. Is this the right way? I have to copy all shared images and trying to maintain the help book will be awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you resolve this?

There's an app available that allows you to author content in multiple languages, then generates the bundle for you if you don't want to mess with this: http://www.putercraft.com.

However, to answer the question, you don't need to copy your help bundle. Maybe your help bundle's Info.plist is missing a key? For example, do you have CFBundleDevelopmentRegion set? I've found that some versions of Help Viewer are picky about plists -  you should look at a working help bundle in another app and make sure you have all the same keys set.

My (working) help bundle has the following general structure:

```
Contents
    Resources
    Info.plist
    images
    en.lproj
        help.helpindex (for english)
        <html content>
        InfoPlist.strings (english title)
    fr.lproj
        help.helpindex (for french)
        <html content>
        InfoPlist.strings (french title)
```

Comment: I've followed this folder structure, but the non-english content doesn't show.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Mac Developer Libary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-SW31):

> For each language you support, you must provide a complete, localized help book in its own resource subdirectory within the Resources directory in the help bundle (see Organizing the Help Book Bundle).
>
> Each localized version of the help book must have a localized book name in the InfoPlist.strings file in the help bundle.

About the shared images, you can put them in the Resources/shrd directory and reference them like this:

> The filepath reference in HTML  tags to artwork in the shrd/ folder should look like this:
>
> On the .html page:
>
> ```
> ../shrd/artworkname.jpg
> ```
>
> On a content page in the pgs/ or other folders:
>
> ```
> ../../shrd/artworkname.jpg
> ```